# Additional parameter adds entropy to the centre of the density function

Tags: distributions, entropy

When an extra shape parameter is added in the distribution than a statement in favour of this parameter is written "extra parameter can control both tail weights and adding entropy to the centre of the density function". I am quite clear about tail weight but cannot understand adding entropy to the centre and how to prove this additional shape parameter add entropy to the centre. Also what advantages are obtained by adding entropy.

Comment: Reference for your statement?

Comment: @cardinal For reference a paper on "The Exponentiated Generalized Class of Distributions" Cordeiro et. al is [here](http://www.jds-online.com/file_download/377/JDS-1086.pdf) see page 2, 4th paragraph last three lines.